# jQuery $(this) inside a plugin function

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, this

I have this jQuery plugin:

```
$.fn.touchBind = function(func) {
  $(this).live('touchmove', function() {
    $(this).addClass('dragged');
  });

  $(this).live('touchend', function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('dragged') == false) {
      func();
    }
  });

  return this;
}
```

and call it like so:

```
$('.the-element').touchBind(function() {
  $(this).hide();
});
```

My problem is that `$(this)` in `$(this).hide()` doesn't refer to `$('.the-element')`, but rather `DOMWindow`. Is there a way I can make this work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change `func();` to `func.call(this);` or `$.proxy(func, this)();`.

You could also use `apply()` (not necessary when `call()` suits) or `bind()` (limited browser support, `$.proxy()` does essentially the same thing).

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$('.the-element').touchBind(function() {
  $('.the-element').hide();
});
```

Comment: I'm aware that I can do this, it just doesn't behave like a normal jQuery plugin. I like being able to use `$(this)`.

Answer (score 0):

@Alex is correct, all you need is to replace `func();` with `func.call(this);` and it will work. However I'd like to point out that you are making 2 redundant calls to jQuery constructor in your plugin:

```
    $.fn.touchBind = function(func) {

    //this already refers to a jQuery object
      this.live('touchmove', function() {

        //this refers to a DOM element inside here
        $(this).addClass('dragged');
      });

      //this already refers to a jQuery object
      this.live('touchend', function() {

         //this refers to a DOM element inside here
        if ($(this).hasClass('dragged') == false) {
          func.call( this );
        }
      });

      return this;
    }
```

You could verify it like this:

```
$.fn.whatIsThis = function(){
return "jquery" in this ? "jQuery object" : "Something else";
};
```

And then:

```
console.log( $("div").whatIsThis() );
//"jQuery object"
```